# send value using __doPostBack

Tags: asp.net

I'm sending a value (id) from javascript like this:

```
__doPostBack('',id)
```

and at the server side I get it like this:

```
var id = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
```

the problem is that sometimes other controls also do stuff and the **var id** also get's value but not with the value I sent, but some control did.

how do I send this value separately so that in var id only the value that I sent using js can be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to hack this I guess is to concat some token prefix like myId_ with id instead of just id as parameter, and parse id back in ASP.NET